# Can you kill sheep with axes?

Tags: kingdom-rush

In [Kingdom Rush](http://www.kongregate.com/games/Ironhidegames/kingdom-rush), the Sorcerer Mage's Polymorph ability turns people into sheep which it says can't be blocked. This almost seems to do more harm than good if I'm using melee people. Can barbarians still hit them with their throwing axes? What about flying sheep, can they hit them?

Comment: I misread the title as "Can you sleep with axes?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the barbarian's flying axe attack can certainly hit sheep as they run pass them. I've set up an experiment and captured the result in [this video](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1722364/Kingdom.ogv). [.ogv, 13mb, sheep killing starts 40 seconds in]

[image]

Comment: ooh, a video. :3